# Retrieving user profile image from Firebase but it's not showing in ImageView, what problem do I face?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this code to retrieve image but it is not showing in ImageView
Java Activity

```
public void showUserInformation(){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user == null){
            return;
        }
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

        if(name == null){
            txtName.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        }
        else {
            txtName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            txtName.setText(name+"");
        }

        tvEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).error(R.drawable.ic_avatar).into(imgAvatar);
    }
```

.XML

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

Log
photoUrl: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A697b2a37-456d-407d-924b-a5c68f63d55b/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1400406661

I don't understand why it is like that, obviously the data Url is returned but the image cannot be retrieved